# Add element at specific position in XML-file C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML-file:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xslt"?>
<Root>
 <Notes>
    <Note>
    <date>1997-07-04T00:00:00</date>
    </Note>
    <Note>
      <date>1997-07-04T00:00:00</date>
    </Note>
</Notes>
</Root>
```

No, I want to add Elements to this XML like the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xslt"?>
<Root>
 <Notes>
    <notedate date="date here"><Note>
    <date>1997-07-04T00:00:00</date>
    </Note></notedate>
    <notedate date="date here"><Note>
      <date>1997-07-04T00:00:00</date>
    </Note></notedate>
</Notes>
</Root>
```

As you can see, I want to encapsulate the `<Note>` Inside a `<notedate>`-element.

How can I specify where to add new elements, both start and endtags, to an XML-file In C#?

Im using XDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, each Note element is replaced:

```
var query=from n in xml.Root.Descendants("Note")
    select n;


foreach(var elem in query.ToList())
    elem.ReplaceWith(new XElement("notedate", new XAttribute("date", "date here"), elem));
```

Comment: I know. But I want to specify WHERE to place this Element In my XML. As you can see, I want my new element to be before <note> and a endtag after </note>

Comment: see update answer. I replace each note element with a new notedate element, and enclosing the old. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You effectively want to wrap each `Note` element with another element, one option is to use [`ReplaceWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302711(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var noteElements = doc.Root.Descendants("Note").ToList();

foreach(XElement noteEl in noteElements)
{
    string noteDateValue = noteEl.Element("date").Value;
    noteEl.ReplaceWith(new XElement("notedate", noteEl, new XAttribute("date", noteDateValue)));
}
// your doc is now updated
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple case is demonstrated here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is the code snippet:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
            "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "</book>");

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

//Create a new node.
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("price");
elem.InnerText="19.95";

//Add the node to the document.
root.AppendChild(elem);

Console.WriteLine("Display the modified XML...");
doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

Comment: I have just learned XDocument, so I want to use XDocument for this.